# Can you focus a popup window from a Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome Extension that does a window.open() when the extensions icon is clicked. (It can't use the traditional Chrome extension popup due to an unrelated bug in Chrome). I'm wondering if there's a way to focus a popup window if its already open. Chrome disables window.focus() but I thought there might be a way to do it in a Chrome Extension.

**Update:**
For anyone interested this is the code I ended up using in my background page:

```
var popupId;

// When the icon is clicked in Chrome
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

  // If popupId is undefined then there isn't a popup currently open.
  if (typeof popupId === "undefined") {

    // Open the popup
    chrome.windows.create({
      "url": "index.html",
      "type": "popup",
      "focused": true,
      "width": 350,
      "height": 520
    }, function (popup) {
      popupId = popup.id;
    }); 

  } 
  // There's currently a popup open
  else {
     // Bring it to the front so the user can see it
    chrome.windows.update(popupId, { "focused": true });  
  }

});

// When a window is closed
chrome.windows.onRemoved.addListener(function(windowId) {
  // If the window getting closed is the popup we created
  if (windowId === popupId) {
    // Set popupId to undefined so we know the popups not open
    popupId = undefined;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of using window.open() use the Chromes chrome.windows.create...   http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/windows.html#method-create
...then in the call back you can record its window.id and then any time you want to make it focused you can use chrome.windows.update.