# PopUp window focus not working on mouseover event but working on click event from a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension in that I am trying to focus a popup window generated from background script of chrome extension. there are links on the page, on hover of them I need to open a popup window with those links, if the user hovers over the link which is already open in the popup window, then rather than opening the popup window again, I just need to focus on the same popup window, but the focus thing isn't working on mouseover but working on click . Is this a chrome bug?

The code till now that I have is:

content.js

```
$(document).on("mouseover", "a", function (event) {
    var viewportwidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var viewportheight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var data = { url: $(this).attr("href"), clientY: viewportwidth, clientX: viewportheight }
    if (data.url.indexOf("://") !== -1) sendMessage(data);
})

function sendMessage(data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(data);
}
```

background.js

```
var win;
var oldUrl ;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(oldUrl !== request.url || win.closed){
            oldUrl = request.url ;
            win &&  win.close();
            win = window.open(request.url, "mywindow", "menubar=0,tittlebar=0,resizable=1,width=1000,height=650" + ",top=" + request.clientY + ",left=" + request.clientX + 100);
            win.onclose = function(){
                oldUrl = "";
            }    
        }
        else{
            alert('hi');
            win.focus();
        }
    });
```

I have the option at this link [Can you focus a popup window from a Chrome Extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8984047/can-you-focus-a-popup-window-from-a-chrome-extension)

This doesn't have much options of popup window, which are required by my extension.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "but not been able to focus the same, when it has been minimized, but that same thing works with click event but not with mouseover." is unclear as to what you are actually doing. It sounds like the user/you are doing some extra manipulation of the UI via mouse. Please describe *exactly* what you are doing and the problem.

Comment: there are links on the page, on hover of them I need to open a popup window with those links, if the user hovers over the link which is already open in the popup window, then rather than opening the popup window again, I just need to focus on the same popup window, but the focus thing isn't working on mouseover but working on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can focus a window by using `chrome.windows.update()`.  However, to do so you need the window ID for the window you want to affect. I did not quickly see a good way to obtain the window ID from the [Window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) returned by [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open). So, I just chose to capture the ID of the window which is next focused after the call to `window.open()`.

The following code uses `chrome.windows.update()` to focus the window:

```
var win;
var oldUrl;
var focusedWinId = null;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(oldUrl !== request.url || win.closed){
        oldUrl = request.url ;
        win && win.close();
        focusedWinId = null; //Flag to remember the next focused window.
        win = window.open(request.url, "mywindow", "menubar=0,tittlebar=0,resizable=1,width=1000,height=650" + ",top=" + request.clientY + ",left=" + request.clientX + 100);
        win.onclose = function(){
            oldUrl = "";
        }
    } else{
        if(focusedWinId !== null){
            chrome.windows.update(focusedWinId,{focused:true});
        }
    }
});

chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(winId){
    if(focusedWinId === null & winId > -1){
        focusedWinId = winId;
    }
});
```

**Just change the window's URL instead of closing and re-opening:**

I found it a bit annoying that the window kept being destroyed and created every time a link with a different URL was hovered. So, I changed the code to only open the window if the window was not already open. If the window is already open, then just change the URL.

Your `win.onclose` both was never running, and did not do anything which affected the code. The only place it was checked was `oldUrl !== request.url || win.closed` and `win.closed` is true under those conditions. Thus, I removed it. If you need `oldUrl` to be cleared, you will need to use a `chrome.windows.onRemoved` listener.

The following code will update the URL for the popup window instead of destroying the window and re-opening a new one when the `request.url` is different than the one currently displayed:

```
var win;
var oldUrl;
var focusedWinId = null;
var popupTabId = null;
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    //win && console.log('closed:',win.closed);
    if(oldUrl !== request.url || win.closed){
        oldUrl = request.url ;
        if(win && !win.closed){
            chrome.tabs.update(popupTabId,{url:request.url});
        } else {
            focusedWinId = null; //Flag to remember the next focused window.
            win = window.open(request.url, "mywindow", "menubar=0,tittlebar=0,resizable=1,width=1000,height=650" + ",top=" + request.clientY + ",left=" + request.clientX + 100);
        }
    } else{
        if(focusedWinId !== null){
            chrome.windows.update(focusedWinId,{focused:true});
        }
    }
});

chrome.windows.onFocusChanged.addListener(function(winId){
    if(focusedWinId === null & winId > -1){
        focusedWinId = winId;
        chrome.windows.get(winId,{populate:true},function(win){
            popupTabId = win.tabs[0].id;
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Makyen, you are a genious my friend, that worked like a charm.

Comment: Makyen The first code is sometimes causing two pop up windows to open. Can you please suggest

Comment: @SahilAgarwal, I did not experience that in my testing. Can you provide the URL of the page on which you are testing and the actions you took to cause the problem? In the first code, you should only end up opening a window if either `win` has become invalid, or `win.close()` has executed. it would be necessary to try to duplicate the issue to figure out what is going on.  If `win.close()` is intermittently not effective (like `win.focus()` was not all the time), then it may be resolved by using [`chrome.windows.remove()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-remove) instead.

Comment: sorry for that, it was occurring because of two instances of same extension. Do you have any idea why the popup window generated from background script doesn't show the address bar

Comment: @SahilAgarwal, No problem. Are you wanting a window with tabs in which this is only one tab among (possibly) many? I'm not sure what you are wanting it to look like.

Comment: @SahilAgarwal, After trying the same `window.open()` code from a content script, there is a difference. I would need to look into why.

Comment: Makyen were you able to find anything on this?

Comment: @SahilAgarwal, I have not had the time to look into this. There are, perhaps, people who would immediately know. I would suggest [asking a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). It is something that should be its own question anyway to let the answer be available to people looking for it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the chrome.windows instead of using plain window? You can use the `chrome.windows.create` function and specify the `focused: true` option. By doing that you can open a new window directly from your extension, that you can easiely focus/blur.

Comment: I have already tried that, but it doesn't have options like setting the top and botton of popup. Can you tell something related the code what I have posted

Comment: @ŁukasTrzewik [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) **does** have options to specify the top and height of the created window.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko, but the `top` and `left` [options are ignored](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) for popups/panels: "This value is ignored for panels."

Comment: Now I have figured out, what the exact problem is, the window popup is working on ciick event but is not working on mouseover. Is this a chrome bug